# Get Payment Method used in order in totals.phtml

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, payment, payment-methods

i'm using Magento 1.9.0.1 and i want to get the used order payment method in the totals.phtml

Here is what i have in: totals.phtml:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getTotals() as $_code => $_total): ?>
    <?php if ($_total->getBlockName()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName(), false); ?>
    <?php else:?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $_code?>">
        <td <?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>>
            <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?></strong>
            <?php else:?>
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?>
            <?php endif?>
        </td>
        <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?>>
            <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?></strong>
            <?php else:?>
            <?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?>
            <?php endif?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

I want to get a simple echo with the the payment method like `<?PHP echo $PaymentMethod; ?>`

How can i get the payment method used for the order ?

Comment: Where do you want to display this? .... order review, order place, admin view order ... etc

Comment: I want to display this in order review :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//get quote
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

//get payment from quote
$quote->getPayment()
```

Comment: This will bring the current session payment method or it will take the payment method used for the finalized order, because i need it for the finalized order.

Comment: Hmz i'm kinda confused here, the order isn't finalized when the totals are displayed right? Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @brentwpeterson where is the link? :D

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `current_order` is define (admin / sales history controller

```
if($order = Mage::registry('current_order')){

    //Get Payment
    $payment = $order->getPayment()

    //Get card type
    $payment->getData('cc_type')

    //Get Payment Info
    $payment->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
    $payment->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();

}
```

Comment: I want to display this in order review like http://mymagento.com/sales/order/view/order_id/181/

Comment: The code above should work

Comment: No it's not: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getPayment() on a non-object in /public_html/beta/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/totals.phtml` Please help me out resolve this problem.

Comment: Can you update your question with your code

Comment: Can we send the original amount which is appear in strong in reorders ?